# Send BitmapSource to task for calculation - wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap, task, bitmapimage

I have two images in my program, I have a function to compare two BitmapSources, the problem is one I convert an ImageSource to BitmapSource and assign that to a variable, and send it to the function inside a task (because the function is rather slow and I prefer to use a task and then update the user when it's done), it gives me an error that the task cannot use this variable because another thread owns it... please help me fix it.

```
private async void btnAnalyze_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (AnalyzeImage?.Status == TaskStatus.Running) await AnalyzeImage;
        var baseSource = (BitmapSource)imgBase.Source;
        var newSource = (BitmapSource)imgNew.Source;
        if (baseSource?.CompareSizeTo(newSource) == false)
        {
            ShowStatus("Images are different in size or at least one of them is null");
            return;
        }
        btnAnalyze.IsEnabled = false;
        ShowStatus();
        try
        {
            AnalyzeImage = Task<BitmapSource>.Factory.StartNew(() => baseSource?.ConvertToBitmap().CompareTo(newSource?.ConvertToBitmap()).BitmapToImageSource());
            InvokeA(() => waitingPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible);
            await AnalyzeImage;
            imgNew.Source = AnalyzeImage.Result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Notify("Error in btnAnalyzeClick", ex, true); }
        finally { InvokeA(() => waitingPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden); }
    }
```

Comment: show some code please?

Comment: I updated, if you want something else, say specifically what... @Slashy

Comment: ConvertToBitmap(), BitmapToImageSource() - are those extension methods?

Comment: @alexm yes, they are, and they do exactly what their name says.

Comment: Which variable is owned by another thread?

Comment: @Devid47: In what method the exception was thrown?  Could it be ConvertToBitmap() ?

Comment: Just call Freeze() on the BitmapSource. That will make it cross-thread accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects derived from [DispatcherObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherobject(v=vs.110).aspx) have *thread affinity*, i.e. once created they are "owned" by the calling thread. In WPF application it is usually UI thread.

If `BimtapSource` instantiation is placed after `await` it will use the current context (UI in this case), which enables the consumption of this object by UI components:

```
private async void btnAnalyze_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (AnalyzeImage?.Status == TaskStatus.Running) await AnalyzeImage;
    var baseSource = (BitmapSource)imgBase.Source;
    var newSource = (BitmapSource)imgNew.Source;
    if (baseSource?.CompareSizeTo(newSource) == false)
    {
        ShowStatus("Images are different in size or at least one of them is null");
        return;
    }
    btnAnalyze.IsEnabled = false;
    ShowStatus();
    try
    {
       waitingPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
       var worker = Task<Bitmap>.Factory.StartNew(() =>        
                      baseSource?.ConvertToBitmap()
                     .CompareTo(newSource?.ConvertToBitmap()));

        var bmp = await worker;

        // The next statement is executed in UI synchronization context
        imageNew.Source = bmp.BitmapToImageSource(); 

    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    { 
       Notify("Error in btnAnalyzeClick", ex, true); 
    }
    finally 
    { 
       waitingPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }
 }
```

Comment: I have done what you said and also moved the conversion of the BitmapSource to Bitmap of both files to before the task.